# Why is this bootstrap modal not working?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My modal doesn't seem to work. I'm using bootstrap 3.0.3. I've tried it once before but it doesn't seem to work now. Did I miss anything?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right titlebar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Upload file
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably receive this error from the console log:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
```

It's because twitter bootstrap js require `jQuery` to run, you need to include `jQuery` first, so change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: THANKS! It works now. Didn't know the order. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

The order of script inclusion is wrong, bootstrap.js depends on jQuery so jQuery need to be included first

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7LbMJ/)

Comment: THANKS! It works now. Didn't know the order. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!